# Is there a better way in C# to reserve long variable name?

Tags: c#

```
var test = Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2.PropertyNameWhichIsBigName
```

I have to use above in many places. How to avoid typing or save few key stroke? is there any shortcut in C#

Comment: Are you accessing a heavily-nested class, or a chain of properties?

Comment: Reserve = reference? Avoid nesting classes. Avoid long property names. [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) helps further.

Comment: @canton7 - just a chain of properties....

Comment: @CDesai Right, then ignore most of these answers. You could define your own private property, local function, or private method which does the property access for you

Comment: @CDesai Please, share the entire sample. If it a chain of properties, how they are being set? Do you need to simplify both getters and setter? Or it's just a nested classes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use Namespace aliases:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces

`using ShortName = Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2;`

And then

`var test = ShortName.PropertyNameWhichIsBigName;`

Comment: Turns out that `Class1`.Subclass1.Subclass2` is a chain of property access, not nested namespaces / types, making this answer incorrect

Answer (score 0):

How about a function:

```
Func<typeOfProperty> someName = () => Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2.PropertyNameWhichIsBigName;
```

if you now call

```
var test = someName();
```

you would get your desired value without having to type the long chain of properties all the time.

Edit:
Just to be clear, if `PropertyNameWhichIsBigName` changes, `someName()` will return the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespace aliasing and just call it in namespaces section in your code, and you can effectively use objects and functions all over the body @canton7 has already written example for that.
or you can use code blocks statements but you have to implement IDisposable, but this can limit your object calling section but you can get benefit fit automatic dispose.

```
 class Class1 
{
   public class Subclass1  
    {
      public  class Subclass2 : IDisposable
        {
            public string PropertyNameWhichIsBigName { get; set; }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2 obj = new Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2())
        {
            string propertiesValue = obj.PropertyNameWhichIsBigName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate a property like that. This would not work! He wants to access the value of a property with the name `PropertyNameWhichIsBigName`.

Comment: Thanks @MirkoBrandt you are right i have called property directly instead of class and also we may have to care about Dispose if tried on nested class here is correct reference:  class Class1   {  public class Subclass1   {  public  class Subclass2 : IDisposable  {  public string PropertyNameWhichIsBigName { get; set; }
                public void Dispose()   { throw new NotImplementedException(); }  }  }  }
    
            using (Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2 obj = new Class1.Subclass1.Subclass2())    {     string propertiesValue = obj.PropertyNameWhichIsBigName;   }